# Implementing Search Bar in Swift

Tags: swift

I have been trying to implement a search bar into my table view to allow users to search through transaction names.

This is the tutorial I am following: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

I have ran into issues with trying to translate the Objective C code into Swift as I am stuck at the 'filterContentForSearchText' line.

Here is the code I currently have for the search bar:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: NSString, scope: NSString) {
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchText)
    searchResults = arrayDataPayments.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
    println(searchResults)
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {

    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString, scope: self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles)
    return true
}
```

Could anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do something like this:

```
self.filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchString, scope: self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex])
```

Comment: That gives me the error 'Could not find member 'objectAtIndex'. If I use         self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString, scope: self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles().objectAtIndex(self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex))          then I get the error '(UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString: String!) -> Bool does not have a member named 'searchBar'.

Comment: That code now runs however unfortunately I get the error 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' on that line of code.

Comment: Check if `scopeButtonTitles` (or any other Optional type in that line of code) is nil.

Comment: @user3746428 To check for nil use an `if` statement: `if variable != nil`. You might want to take a look at [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=fatal%20error%3a%20unexpectedly%20found%20nil%20while%20unwrapping%20an%20Optional%20value).